# how to maintain the Image Position and Size for all size of Devices in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-designer

I have layout like below image and I have designed using image view and image button for this images.  while run for other devices its alignment and size is Varies:

- so Which layout want to use
- Size based on design or device based  or
- any technique is there for the responsive design

  [image]

**i'm using only on Landscape mode

Comment: I'd use a RelativeLayout. Position a dummy View (0dp by 0dp) in the center. And place the other Views relatively to that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways to do this.
The easiest way is to use androids grid layout and build it that way,
this takes a bit of getting used to but it works well.

the 2nd way is to make alot of values folders and ajusting dimens in them:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html